# Phonegap file upload to the asmx web service

Tags: android, ios, cordova, file-upload, asmx

I'm trying to upload image file to the asmx web service from Android and ios device but i'm getting error which list of below:

for Android:
FileNotFoundException on the server
Error on FileTransfer.upload
Error on FileTransfer.execute
IOException: Received error from server.
"http_status":500, "code":1

for iOS:
FileNotFoundException on the server
Error on FileTransfer.upload
Error on FileTransfer.execute
IOException: Received error from server.
"http_status":500, "code":3

I'm using Icenium for development and service_url parameter of ft.upload() method is working i can call web service on browser but when i try to use in my project i got same error.

IIS logs below:

Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5

Version: 1.0

Date: 2013-02-22 11:00:07

Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User- Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken

```
2013-02-22 11:00:07 192.168.1.103 POST /ExpenseService.asmx/UploadFile - 40201 - 78.189.173.183 Camera%20Sample%20Official/1.0+CFNetwork/609+Darwin/13.0.0 500 0 0 287 2013-02-22 11:01:28 192.168.1.103 POST /ExpenseService.asmx/UploadFile - 40201 - 78.189.173.183 Camera%20Sample%20Official/1.0+CFNetwork/609+Darwin/13.0.0 500 0 0 144
```

my cordova version 2.2.0. Any ideas what i did wrong?

ASMX Service:

```
#region FileUpload
    [WebMethod]
    //[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string UploadFile()
    {
        try
        {
            File.WriteAllText(@"d:\test.txt", "hede");
            HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
            if (file == null)
                return null;
            string targetFilePath = @"d:\" + file.FileName;
            file.SaveAs(targetFilePath);
            return file.FileName.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(@"d:\uploader.txt", ex.Message.ToString());
            return null;
        }

    }
    #endregion
```

Client Side:

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions(); 
options.chunkedMode  = false;
options.fileKey = "ficheFile";
console.log('imageFileName: ' + imageFileName);    
options.fileName = imageFileName; 
options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
console.log('imageSrc: ' + imageSrc);

var ft = new FileTransfer(); 
ft.upload(imageSrc, encodeURI("http://mydomain:40201/ExpenseService.asmx/UploadFile"), win, fail, options);
```

Here is my adb logcat:

```
E/FileTransfer(11472): {"target":"http:\/\/mydomain:40201\/ExpenseService.asmx\/SaveFile","source":"file:\/\/\/mnt
\/sdcard\/Android\/data\/com.telerik.Camera_Sample_Official\/cache\/1361950930301.jpg","http_status":500,"code":1}
E/FileTransfer(11472): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://78.189.173.183:40201/ExpenseService.asmx/SaveFile
E/FileTransfer(11472):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(H
ttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521)
E/FileTransfer(11472):  at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.getInputStream(FileTransfer.java:480)
E/FileTransfer(11472):  at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.access$400(FileTransfer.java:62)
E/FileTransfer(11472):  at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer$1.run(FileTransfer.java:402)
E/FileTransfer(11472):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
E/FileTransfer(11472):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
E/FileTransfer(11472):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
D/CordovaLog(11472): Error Code: 1
D/CordovaLog(11472): : Line 1153648589 : Error Code: 1
I/Web Console(11472): Error Code: 1 at :1153648589
```

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

httpstaus 500 is a server error.
It seems that there's a bug in your UploadFile function.

You may attach w3wp.exe to process for testing your service

Comment: Visual Studio didn't trigger. :\

Comment: It seems that test.txt or uploader.txt has not been found. You may comment some code of IO operation first. If the exception do not show again, I am very sure that you should check your webservice code.

Comment: if test.txt or uploader.txt don't exist, WriteAllText() method gonna create file automatically. if the file exist then method will overwrite again. You can check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143376.aspx for method. 

I know the problem is on webservice because i got http 500 error. this means problem on server side. Is there any spesific configuration for file uploader which i missed?